# SQL Update statement with 2 EXISTS clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, exists

I am trying to update a value to be NULL where tracker_unique_id can be found in ab_split_tracker_unique_link where that ones ab_split_id can be found in a 3rd table ab_split_candidate.

I cant do it by giving it different values as they can be different from user to user on locals

```
UPDATE trustpilot_links SET `invite_after_enquiry` = NULL 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT tracker_unique_id, ab_split_tracker_unique_link.ab_split_candidate_id 
    FROM ab_split_tracker_unique_link 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT ab_split_candidate_id
        FROM ab_split_candidate LEFT JOIN ab_split 
        ON ab_split_candidate.ab_split_id = ab_split.ab_split_id WHERE ab_split.reference="review_invite_after_enquiry"
    )
);
```

Edit:
Table examples
Trustpilot Links

`trustpilot_link_id | invite_after_enquiry | tracker_unique_id
1                    1                       123
2                    0                       1234`

ab_split_tracker_unique_link
`tracker_unique_id | ab_split_id 
1234                 32`

Ab Split 
`ab_split_id | reference 
32              review_invite_after_enquiry`

I want to set values to null if there tracker cannot be found in table ab_split_tracker_unique_link with an ab_split_id that is equal to review_invite_after_enquiry in ab_split

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but I can already tell you, that you're using `exists` wrong. `exists` doesn't really care about the value you're selecting in the subquery. It just checks if a row is returned and stops at the very first finding. When you don't specify a `where` clause, the result will always be true, as long as there is any row in the table.

Comment: From the non-standard quotes I gather this is MySQL?

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Okay, sorry i've never used exists I just htought this would be the way of doing it.
Yes this is MySQL
Sorry man, gone and added more details to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subqueries are not related to their parent queries as they should be. Let's look at your inner-most query:

```
SELECT ab_split_candidate_id
FROM ab_split_candidate 
LEFT JOIN ab_split ON ab_split_candidate.ab_split_id = ab_split.ab_split_id
WHERE ab_split.reference = 'review_invite_after_enquiry'
```

Well, first of all your `WHERE` clause dismisses outer-joined records, so this is essentially an `INNER JOIN`. But then: either there are such records or not. This has nothing to do with the record your are potentially updating, nor with the `ab_split_tracker_unique_link` you are looking up.

So either you are updating all records or none.

We would rather expect something like

```
UPDATE trustpilot_links tl
SET invite_after_enquiry = NULL 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM ab_split_tracker_unique_link stul
  WHERE stul.tracker_unique_id = tl.tracker_unique_id
  AND ...
);
```

So add WHERE clauses that relate the subqueries to their parent queries.